# error while uploading my app to google play - android

Tags: android, upload, apk

I keep getting this error while uploading my apk. file to google play:

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(13524): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x01080049
ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.flags"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges=  "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example``.flags.WaitScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
  </manifest>
```

Things I've tried:
.1. Changing the label attribute to "@null" - didn't work.
.2. Putting my icon image in all of the drawables folders - including "drawable"(without extenstions)
.3. Changing the icon image name.
.4. Putting strings.xml in all of the values folders that I have.

Comment: and the image file you are trying to use is included in your project...???

Comment: Yea, sure. The icon launcher is available is all of my drawables folders.

Comment: and if you install the app in your phone or tablet like when you are debbuging... Do you see the icon launcher???

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: can you post an screenshot of your project structure, what I want to see is the drawable folders with its content!

Comment: Nevermind guys I solved this problem by simply importing some system icons that I used in my project into my workspace.